# Deleting a list after creating an iterator object from it

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

I am trying to understand the concept of iterators in python and tried this in Python 3.5.2.

```
x = list(range(1000))    # size of x is 9112 bytes
y = iter(x)              # size of y is 56 bytes
del x
x = list(y)              # size of x is again 9112 bytes
```

How does the iterator store the information about the sequence it has to generate?

It does not contain all the elements but even after deleting the original list we are still able to reproduce the original list from the iterator?

If it does not contain all the elements how does it know which is the next element even after deleting `x`?

Comment: short answer....because it has enough information encapsulated inside it to recreate the original sequence...when you consume it

Answer (score 2):

Because iterators have enough details stored in them to enable them generate the next element of a sequence without having that "next element" in memory.

To understand what is going on let's create our own fake iterator

```
class Fakeiterator:
    def __init__(self, range_list):
        self.current = range_list[0]
        self.high = range_list[-1]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current > self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.current += 1
            return self.current - 1
```

In our `__init__` method we've stored enough details (the start point and end point of our iterator) to enable us generate the next element without actually having it in memory. As far as we have this information, even though we're given a list containing 2000 elements we just need to know the start and end point

in our `__next__` method anytime we ask for the next element in our iterator, The iterator simply increments the current counter and return it back to us.

Lets test our iterator:

```
>>> x = list(range(5))
>>> y = Fakeiterator(x)
>>> del x
>>> list(y)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

The `list` constructor repeatedly calls `__next__` until `StopIteration` is raised by our iterator and that's at the point where the current element is higher than the maximum element we stored at the creation of the iterator.

But in your case calling `iter(x)` on a list, returns a `list_iterator` object that **STORES** x internally. `x` is still stored but not with the name `x` anymore.

On why `getsizeof` returns a lower size which as you expected is supposed to be greater or at least equal to the size of the original list. from the docs

> sys.getsizeof(object[, default]) Return the size of an object in
>   bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will
>   return correct results, but this does not have to hold true for
>   third-party extensions as it is implementation specific.
>
> **Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is
>   accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.**
>
> If given, default will be returned if the object does not provide
>   means to retrieve the size. Otherwise a TypeError will be raised.
>
> getsizeof() calls the object’s **sizeof** method and adds an
>   additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the
>   garbage collector.

To demonstrate that let's write a quick script

```
import sys

x = [1, 2, 3]

print(sys.getsizeof(x))

class storex():
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

y = storex(x)

print(sys.getsizeof(y))
print(y.param, sys.getsizeof(y.param))
```

When you run the script. this is the output (on my machine, but it should be the same with yours)

```
88
56
[1, 2, 3] 88
```

even though the list `[1, 2, 2]` is 88 bytes long, when we store it as an attribute of `storex` it doesn't automatically make `storex` become larger than it. because `storex` refers to it. it's not part of `storex` directly

But on printing the size of `y.param`, we can see that it's still the same size as the original `[1, 2, 3]` list

Also `del` doesn't delete the object from memory, it simply unbinds the name `x` so x won't refer to any object in memory. the value of x will only be discarded (garbage collected) when there is no reference to it again

Here is a demonstration of what i mean

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> class y: pass
... 
>>> y.x = x
>>> id(x), id(y.x)
(140177507371016, 140177507371016)
>>> del x
>>> id(y.x)
140177507371016
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>>
```

deleting `x` doesn't automatically delete `[1,2,3]` which `y.x` points to, even though their id's show that they both pointed to the same object in memory.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for this late reply. But I still have a few doubts:

Comment: a) I just posted the range as an example. In that case, it's pretty easy to store the information using the low and high values and the step. However, what if the sequence is random ?

Comment: (I am sorry but I don't know why I am unable to edit my own comments and pressing enter keeps posting every sentence as a new comment.)  b) If I delete x, then the iterator is still depending on that chunk of memory right, otherwise it will not be able to produce the values. So, in terms of memory, its only helpful when we use inbuilt iterables like range in Python 3.5. In my example, Python couldn't tell internally that its a range and so it would need the entire list stored in memory and hence there would be no reason, besides understanding the concept, to do what I did in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I know, del x does not del the value in the memory since your y is still referring it. It is kind of pointer. x and y is referring to the same memory.

when you do del x, python will dereference the x and do garbage collection.

while by doing x=list(y), you are pointing the memory to x again.